# Add content in the scrolling working tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add content in the working tabs.(link below)
Please tell me how to you will fix it ?

Visit https://codepen.io/benfrain/pen/wJgZYP

What I add class in html for content add

```
<div class="pn-ProductNav_Wrapper">
<nav id="pnProductNav" class="pn-ProductNav">
    <div id="pnProductNavContents" class="pn-ProductNav_Contents">
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link" aria-selected="true">Chairs</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Tables</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Cookware</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Beds</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Desks</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Flooring</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Lighting</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Mattresses</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Solar Panels</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Bookcases</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Mirrors</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Rugs</a>  
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Curtains &amp; Blinds</a>  
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Frames &amp; Pictures</a>  
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Wardrobes</a>  
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Storage</a>  
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Decoration</a>  
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Appliances</a>
         <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Racks</a>
        <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Worktops</a>
    </div>

</nav>
    <button id="pnAdvancerLeft" class="pn-Advancer pn-Advancer_Left" type="button">
        <svg class="pn-Advancer_Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 551 1024"><path d="M445.44 38.183L-2.53 512l447.97 473.817 85.857-81.173-409.6-433.23v81.172l409.6-433.23L445.44 38.18z"/></svg>
    </button>
    <button id="pnAdvancerRight" class="pn-Advancer pn-Advancer_Right" type="button">
        <svg class="pn-Advancer_Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 551 1024"><path d="M105.56 985.817L553.53 512 105.56 38.183l-85.857 81.173 409.6 433.23v-81.172l-409.6 433.23 85.856 81.174z"/></svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is JavaScript
Visit https://codepen.io/benfrain/pen/wJgZYP

Thanks

Comment: what content and where you mean? please explain with more details.

Comment: EmRa228 I want add any text(content) in the tabs div.I don't understand how to I add text(content) in the tabs Div(bottom at the tabs navigation). 
For example:- Please look here https://www.codeply.com/go/pynlrrCX71
"Home" navigation has a text "Same as example 1 but we have now styled the tab's corner gdhgfghfgh"
so i want same text tab in my "chairs" navigation.

Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution. First you must replace the  with  since click events on anchors will not propagate. Second, add a property to each one of the spans like data-tab-id="div1" and so for...third, add divs with matching id's of those defined in the spans, and by default, set to visible only the first div. Those divs will contain the content you want to display. Now, on the onclick event of each span, get the value of property data-tab-id, and then hide all divs first, and make visible only the one with the matching id, and that's all, you will have a tab control working 100%.